# How do I self size a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am wanting to self size my cell in my Detail View Controller. How do I go about doing this? I have looked up on many tutorials, and I have been able to self size on other apps, but not here. So, how can I do it, and what's the error?

Thanks.

Here is an image of my constraints: [image: Click here]

I have implemented this code in the `viewDidLoad()` method of the view controller:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I have implemented this code in the Detail View Controller class:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 500
}
```

The language I am using is Swift.

Here is an image of what it first looked like: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMqp5.png)

Comment: That's not an image of your constraints. Ah, it is now. But it's not very helpful.

Comment: Aha! It's there now @Fogmeister

Comment: What do you want? Just tell me @Fogmeister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. I edited the constant of the bottom margin of the stack view. I changed it from 206 to 16.

Answer (score 0):

You shooed properly set methods auto resize to their content:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

In you're case you should set properly constraints for each element of the cell for proper auto resize.

Comment: I added these methods in Swift, and then it only showed 3 lines of text. I'll add an image to the question.

Comment: So you should set constraints properly for cell

Comment: I removed one constraint which limited the number of lines. Nothing happened when I added your code. What constraint am I missing?

Comment: The image of the simulator has been added

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app/ this link contains nice tutorial about UITableViewAutomaticDimension and proper constraints usage

Comment: This doesn't show me any information about the constraints and what I need to add.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in **viewDidLoad()**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Remember here estimatedRowHeight is the minimum height you need.
And in the **heightForRowAtIndexPath** method add following code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Read my answer. Its already had fixed this issue. I can't tick it off until tomorrow.